# Flexible Search dynamic attribute

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub, flexible-search, dynamic-attributes

I have a problem with Flexible Search, I have a dynamic attribute ("available parts") in the TimeSlotInstance entity, I would like to show the value of this dynamic attribute in the "remaining availability" column of my query (obviously for each time slot instance), how can I do this? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use FlexibleSearch with dynamic attributes. You can only FlexSearch attributes that can be saved in the database. i.e. non-dynamic attributes.

Comment: so which strategy should I use?

Comment: @John Use Java code to get the data. i.e. Use the Model's getter method of the dynamic attribute

Comment: I did, I basically took all the timeslotinstances of a given day (via a trivial query), I cycled this list and for each element I get the value of the dynamic attribute, but how can I put this value in the column where it should be?

Comment: @John You can't get it via FlexSearch, because FlexSearch gets data from DB. Dynamic Attribute values are not saved in DB; they are configured as `persistence=dynamic` in items.xml. They're calculated on the fly using Java. So, you need to use Java to get those values.

Comment: Hi, yes but how could I do put those value in a column? Basically, I have to attach a cvs file containing values including 'area', 'day', 'slotAvailable15/17' and 'slotAvailable18/20'. The query I made initially returns timeslots which I filter by slot15/17 and slot18/20 but how do I populate the 4 columns and pass them to the csv?